# AWS RDS MySQL / Slow Query Log

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm trying to analyze slow queries on my system and I read that I should enable the "Slow Query Log'. I curious how I can I view this log when I'm using an instance of MySQL hosted on Amazon Web Service's RDS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you know there is slow log table? It is called `mysql.slow_log`:

```
mysql> show create table mysql.slow_log\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: slow_log
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `slow_log` (
  `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `query_time` time NOT NULL,
  `lock_time` time NOT NULL,
  `rows_sent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rows_examined` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `db` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `last_insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sql_text` mediumtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Slow log'
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

There are two variables you must activate to start recording slow queries in mysql.slow_log:

- [**slow_query_log**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log)
- [**log_output**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_output)

Here is the situation

```
mysql> show variables like 'log_output';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| log_output    | TABLE |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'slow_query_log';
+----------------+-------+
| Variable_name  | Value |
+----------------+-------+
| slow_query_log | OFF   |
+----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

[**log_output**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_output) is already defaulted to `TABLE`. You will need to enable [**slow_query_log**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log). Here is what you must do:

### If your RDS Instance has no DB Parameter Group...

1. Spin up an AmazonRDS MySQL Instance that uses a DB Parameter Group.
2. Edit the DB Parameter Group by setting the slow_query_log to 1
3. Restart the DB Instance

### If your RDS Instance has DB Parameter Group...

1. Edit the DB Parameter Group by setting the slow_query_log to 1
2. Restart the DB Instance

Once the Instance has been restarted, login to mysql and run this query

```
mysql> SELECT SLEEP(15);
```

Since the default for [long_query_time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) is 10 seconds, the query `SELECT SLEEP(15);` should show up in `mysql.slow_log`. Read the RDS Documentation to see if there are any limits on the table.

## CAVEAT

Here is a fair warning. Notice `mysql.slow_log` is a CSV file. The table has no key. While you can query the table, it will do full table scans. It would be great if you can do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log ENGINE=MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log ADD INDEX (start_time);
```

Then, you can query very fast for date and time ranges. I tried to run this and I get this:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log ENGINE=MyISAM;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'lwdba'@'%' to database 'mysql'
mysql>
```

Check the RDS Documentation to see if Amazon can do this for you.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: You get the access denied because RDS doesn't give you SUPER privileges.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much this totally answer my questions.

Comment: @ceejayoz how can we overcome SUPER privileges error on RDS?

Comment: @chetanmekha Depends what you're trying to do, but the answer is largely "you don't".

Answer (score 2):

You can also copy the table to a new one in a different db and make the new one MyISAM:

```
create table my_slow_logs as select * from mysql.slow_log;
alter table my_slow_logs engine=MyISAM;
```

(then `select from my_slow_logs...`)

Amazon RDS allows this as long as you do this outside the MySQL database.

Comment: I am sorry I am just noticing this. I can use this.